# Applying Chinese Remainder Therorem for a set of pairwise non-coprime modulos

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find a number $x$ such that:
>
> $x \equiv 1 \mod m$ for $m = 2$ to $18$
>
> $x \equiv 0 \mod 19$

I think the problem can be solved using Chinese Remainder Theorem, but the theorem requires all modulos to be pairwise coprime. Here, the modulos ($2$ to $19$) are not pairwise coprime.

Is there any general procedure to create a subset of pairwise coprime modulos which will give the value of $x$?

Will this procedure work for all problems of the form given below?

> Find a number $x$ such that:
>
> $x \equiv a \mod m$ for finite given pairs of "$a$" and "$m$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the system of congruence relation doesn't have to have a solution if the moduli aren't coprime. Anyway here's a way how to solve the system then. Decompose the composite moduli into power of primes. In your example you can write:

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod {12} \iff 
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\ 
x \equiv 1 \pmod 3
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Now if you obtain a contradiction, like having an equation $x \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ in your system you can conclude that the system has no solution. Also note that the equation $x \equiv a \pmod{p^k} \implies x \equiv a \pmod{p^{k-1}}$, so we can get rid of the smaller powers of a prime if there's no contradiction as above. Hence we can rewrite the above system as:

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x \equiv 1 \pmod {16} \\ 
x \equiv 1 \pmod 9 \\
x \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
x \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
x \equiv 1 \pmod {11} \\
x \equiv 1 \pmod {13} \\
x \equiv 1 \pmod {17} \\
x \equiv 0 \pmod {19} \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

This one can be solved using the CRT.

Answer (score 3):

In this case there is a shortcut. Choose $x = 18! + 1$ and note that $19 \mid x$.